# Javascript: bit operators with "fluent" methods/interfaces boolean tests for a conditional return value

Tags: javascript

**EDIT: SOLUTION:**

Answer: per the comments below. Logic operators `&&` and `||` work fine.

```
 bitwise(bool) {
    // Replace this 
    // this.valid = this.valid & (bool >> 0) 
    // with this
    this.valid = this.valid && bool  
 }
```

**Problem:**

I’m using a builder type pattern along with fluent methods to create a flexible approach for testing values with the result cast toBoolean() or toFail(). Maintaining state of the collective assertions led me down the bit operator path, however, esLint and IDEs tend to warn against using bit operators

**Expected outcome (return values):**

- `toBoolean()`: will return the collective assertions
- `toFail()`: will return original value or fail if any of the assertions fail

**Current Solution:**
Bit operations on boolean: as per my current solution.

**Possible Alternative Solutions:**

- `Array.every() or Array.some()`: a more elegant approach would be a
  callback stack, but still need a logic approach to maintain collective state
- Lengthy conditional expression: `!A || !B || !C` - doesn't scale, static

**Question**

**Are bit operators the only/best approach**, or is there a better approach to implementing this **fluent approach**?

```
 class Validator {
  constructor(any) {
    this.any = any
    this.valid = true
  }
  bitwise(bool) {
    this.valid = this.valid & (bool >> 0)
    !this.valid || this.orFail()
  }
  isValue() {
    this.bitwise(isValue(this.any)) // isValue tests for null and undefined
    return this
  }
  isObject() {
    this.bitwise(isObject(this.any))
    return this
  }
  isNotEmpty() {
    this.bitwise(!isEmpty(this.any))
    return this
  }
  toBoolean(){
    return this.valid
  }
  orFail(message = ""){
    if (!this.valid) {
      throw new InvalidProperty(`TypeError: property is invalid ${message}`);
    }
    return this.any
  }
}
```

**Example Implementation:**

```
const makeValidator = (any) => new Validator(any)


const isHydratedObjectOrFail = (any) => makeValidator(any)
  .isValue()
  .isNotEmpty()
  .isObject()
  .toFail()

const isObject = (any) => makeValidator(any)
  .isObject()
  .toBoolean()
```

Comment: Bitwise operators on boolean primitive values is kind-of weird. The operators are for doing bitwise operations (obviously) on *numbers* (32-bit integers). It's not clear how they make your code any clearer than `&&` and `||` code would be.

Comment: I don't understand what you're using (or think you're using) bit operators for. You're not maintaining a bitfield. Also `bool >> 0` is a weird way to convert a boolean to a number. You should use `Number(bool)` instead to make your intention clear.

Comment: Please avoid `!this.valid || this.orFail()`. Write `if (!this.valid) this.orFail()`

Comment: @Bergi the style guides advise the same, but honestly makes it more difficult to read and feels asymmetrical .. lol. I assume it is a heap/memory issue?

Comment: @Pointy organically got to that point with something that seems reasonable at that point, but which Ive now forgotten ... lol ... works fine with && and II now - thanks

Comment: @Bergi Perhaps you meant to write `if (this.valid)`?

Comment: @InSync Right, I read `&&` (which is the more common form of this antipattern) instead of `||`. Just demonstrates how confusing this is :-) And no, Nolan, there is no memory issue with using normal `if` statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need bitwise operators to work with booleans. Just use the logical and (`&&`) operator.

```js
this.valid = this.valid && bool;
// or with compound assignment:
this.valid &&= bool;
```

Comment: You can even do [`&&=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND_assignment)